# How do i make a new album in the HTC Photos application?

Tags: 2.1-eclair, htc-hero, photos

I have an HTC Hero (with the Android 2.1 update). For the longest time, I've wanted to create new albums in the Photos application and can't for the life of me figure out how to do it. It has a bunch of default albums like "My Favroties" "All photos" and such. I just want to create my own albums so I can organize some pictures, like an album of all the pictures of my ridiculously cute niece. Anyone know how to do that? Or can suggest a better photo management application for Android 2.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually quite simple just hard to figure out.

1. Install a file manager app ([Astro](http://www.appbrain.com/app/astro-file-manager/com.metago.astro), [inKa File Manager](http://www.appbrain.com/app/inka-file-manager/com.mhoffs.filemanager))
2. Using a file manager app navigate to **sdcard > media** folder
3. Create a new folder

Place all your photos into that newly created folder. It may take some time but eventually the new photo album will appear inside HTC's Gallery app.

Comment: No idea how you figured that one out. Would you suggest just using a different application? Or follow these steps and stick with HTC's app?

Comment: @Chaulky It really depends on how you want to manage your photo albums. If you want to be able to move photos in the album through the app then you can't using HTC's Gallery app. But on the other hand if you don't need to move photos in through the app (or even if you do but not too regularly) then this just saves you having to find another gallery app.